# Want to move cursor across multiple content editable divs depending on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I am building a block-based text editor where each element we input is a block. For example if we have the following content to be input as a content:

Assume this is the html output i need.

```
Hello There
First Paragraph
Second paragraph
```

So in editor storage, these will be stored as blocks like these:

```
[
    {
        "type": "text",
        "content": "Hello There",
        "element": "h1"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "content": "First Paragraph",
        "element": "p"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "content": "Second Paragraph",
        "element": "p"
    }
]
```

In the editor, I am abstracting these things and allowing the user to edit content visually, like we could do in a text editor, using content-editable attribute on the tags selected by the user. So it is essentially a WYSIWYG type editor.

Now the issue that I am facing is that like we traverse within the content in any editor, using arrow keys (up and down especially), is not being handled natively by the browser because of the elements being physically different than each other. So how can I, on tap of keyboard buttons (up and down), navigate the cursor programmatically so that user feels like it is not using any new system and just another text editor. 
I have tried with the window selection API, and currently I have only reached the extent where I am able to traverse from one block to another (say from paragraph 1 to heading), but the position can either be set to start or the end, I am not able to find how do I set it to the exact position that it was in.

For example, say that cursor is after **third** character in the paragraph, and the user clicks up arrow key, it should go to headings the third character and so on.

Sorry for a very long question and description. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Can't you add all the elements to a `contentEditable` parent ?

Comment: Can't you keep track of your cursor's position on every keypress and so when you move from one block to another block you know which position to go to?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Prawinsoni, I will try that and see if it works.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Hey @SpiritOfDragon, I had to drop that feature due to timeline but did find a direction with which this was possible.
This is a video to explain the working and idea behind Draft.js (Built by team at Facebook)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feUYwoLhE_4

Comment: @Chintan Palan thank you for replying. I had a look at draft.js, but the problem is that it's tightly coupled with reactjs. I would need more of a pure js solution. Had a look at couple of other editor frameworks but nothing seems to be customized easily.

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon My suggestion was not to use Draft JS but study the idea behind it and how did they achieve it in React JS. For normal core js I think with the help of Selection API, it's quite easily possible. But for react, it was a bit hard as it is a declarative framework and should not try to control the dom directly, so the way they did it was they created draft.js so that they could control it in a correct manner and provide a declarative API around it.
Just a little bit more time and docs reading around Selection API should help you solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm looking at the video and it seems to be useful. Will check that out and read a bit about selection API and try implementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to drop that feature due to timeline but did find a direction with which this was possible. This is a video to explain the working and idea behind Draft.js (Built by the team at Facebook)

https://youtube.com/watch?v=feUYwoLhE_4

It provides an overall way to solve the problem that we are facing above, to control the content-editable in React JS.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice es configurar como editable  al nodo padre cuando presiono las teclas arriba o abajo, después quito esta propiedad, ejemplo en svelte pero es análogo.

```html
<script>
let boolean = false;
function onKeyDown(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40){
     boolean = true;
     setTimeout(()=>{
       boolean = false;
       setTimeout(()=>{
         let nextnode = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
         nextnode.focus();
      },0)
     },0)
   }
   if (e.which === 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
</script>

<div  contenteditable={boolean} class="editor" on:keydown={onKeyDown}>
    <p contenteditable="true"  >hola1</p>
    <p contenteditable="true"  >hola1</p>
    <p contenteditable="true"  >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p contenteditable="true"  >hola1 Lorem ipsum dolor s sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p contenteditable="true"  >hola1L</p>
</div>

<style media="screen">
p{
  outline:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution.
We just use english language here. Thank you.